# React accessing useState within child/sibling

Tags: reactjs

I have a form component `InputContainer` composed of an input `TextField` and button `SubmitButton`

```
import { useState } from "react"

function TextField() {
    const [input, setInput] = useState("")
    return (
        <input
            type="text"
            value={input}
            placeholder="..."
            onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
        />
    )
}

function SubmitButton() {
    return <button></button>
}

function InputContainer() {
    const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        // ...
    }
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <TextField />
            <SubmitButton />
        </form>
    )
}
```

I need to ensure that the `value` managed by `setInput` inside of `TextField` gets reset on any submit (whether triggered by enter key or button click.

I'm not sure what the best way to do this is, given that the `useState` hook is encapsulated within `TextField` and not accessible in the parent or sibling component.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the target elements from the form submit event to interact with the input fields.

```js
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const inputElement = e.target.elements[0];
  
  // get the value
  const inputValue = inputElement.value;

  // reset the value
  inputElement.value = '';

  // ...
};
```

However, note that this is not the React way of doing things. React will not know that the value is updated and your other states will quickly go out of sync and cause all sorts of issues.

In this situation, I would recommend that you make the `TextField` component a [controlled comment](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components#controlled-and-uncontrolled-components) and handle the state at the parent container level.